# Node JS Socket.IO and HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, socket.io, backend

( I am a Beginner ).

**why I should use an http request - response in Node JS when i can use the Socket.IO library?
which are the advanteges of http request - response ?**

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Why you should use Socket.IO when you can use SOAP, SMTP, SNMP, FTP, Telnet, SSH, SCP, SMB, NFS, RTSP, BGP, RPC, SIP, BitTorrent, BOOTP, DNS, IMAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web-sockets(Socket.io) and HTTP both are communication protocols. HTTP uses HTTP:// or HTTPS:// and web-socket uses ws:// or wss:// to communicate with client.

Web-sockets are designed to maintain real time connection with client. But HTTP not maintaining real time connection with client. It response to the request of the client then terminate connection with client.

**So if server only provide something that doesn't change in real time or the client doesn't expect to see changes in real time then having real time connection to client is a waste of server resources(server load, traffic, etc.).**

Example: Think you are searching something in google. Search results appeared in google is same as after 1 hour(or more) for the same keyword. search results are not change in real time. So think if google server use socket connection instead of HTTP connection with clients. Google servers have to maintain billions of simultaneous connections with their clients for nothing.

Also read [performance comparison between web-sockets and HTTP.](https://blog.feathersjs.com/http-vs-websockets-a-performance-comparison-da2533f13a77)

Comment: thank you so much. Your answer is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Http requests are the main form of communication on the web. They are used by the client (your browser) to ask something from the server.

Socket.IO is used for 2 way communications between a client and a server. (Socket.IO uses Websockets for communication, or other fallback methods if the client does not support it)

The question here is what are you building ? A website => use simple requests. An online game => Socket.IO

If you need a two way communication, then use Socket.IO, overwise requests are just fine ;)